# How do I report results back to the main process from multiple processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I currently have 18 functions that perform different sets of validations on large XML files. I've created a custom `ValidationWarning` class that extends `UserWarning`, and these functions raise warnings for each validation failure. In the end, I need to produce an XLSX report containing all of the failures (identifying information for each failure is available in the `ValidationWarning` object).

I'm planning to spawn a process for each function (I saw examples where tasks were placed in a `JoinableQueue`, but I don't understand why this is necessary, unless the task list will be modified later). The order of the validation failures is irrelevant, and I don't need to see the results until all of the validations have finished. Should I replace the `showwarning()` function for each validation function to write to a `list` returned by `Manager()`? I can export the results to XLSX after joining all of the processes. Is this better than writing to a `Queue`? `Queue` may be faster, but writing results isn't a bottleneck, and I don't understand how I'd solve the following problem (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines):

> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate.

Is there a better approach that I'm ignoring? To my understanding, I can't use a `catch_warnings` context manager in the main process and expect it to catch warnings from each validation process, although I haven't tested it yet (edit: I tested it, and, as expected, it fails). Writing to XLSX directly instead of getting all of the results first also sounds difficult, because I'd need to create a blank XLSX file and update it in each process while managing access to the shared XLSX file.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you had a look at `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: `Pool` wasn't in the tutorial I read (http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/), so I wasn't even aware of it until you mentioned it. Conceptually, `Pool` makes sense to me--modify each validation function to return a list of failures, and aggregate the lists as the results become available. However, how do I even write the warnings to a local variable in each validation function, when I can't use `catch_warnings` ([it isn't thread-safe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings))? I can replace `showwarning()`, but I don't call it explicitly to choose the output list.

Comment: Maybe I'm too worried about `catch_warnings`. I hacked together a bit of ugly test code (I'll look into using `map_async` or another alternative when I write my real code), trying to hit the failure condition associated with replacing and later restoring `showwarning()`, but I didn't. Here's my test code, hosted on Ideone only because my firm blocks everything else I'm aware of, even though Ideone doesn't support `multiprocessing`: http://ideone.com/OQBxHL

I'm still very scared to go against the docs, unless I'm confusing thread safety with a different concept for processes...

Answer (score 1):

I work at the same firm, saw your mail on the company mailing list :)

Why don't you try something like this :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep
import warnings

def catchwarnings(arg):
    msg, num = arg
    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
        if num == 4:
            sleep(10)
        print 'catchfxn called with num=%d' % num
        warnings.simplefilter("always")

        # Trigger a warning.
        for i in xrange(num):
            warnings.warn("{} - #{}".format(msg, i), UserWarning)
    return w

def printwarnings(w):
    print w

if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Pool(18)
    for i in [('waaa', 3), ('squeee', 4), ('maaaa', 2)]:
        p.apply_async(catchwarnings, args=(i, ), callback=printwarnings)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Gives this :

```
catchfxn called with num=3
catchfxn called with num=2
[<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a4d0>, <warnings.WarningMessage object at    0x10559a710>, <warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a750>]
[<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a510>, <warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a550>]
catchfxn called with num=4
[<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a650>, <warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a690>, <warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a4d0>, <warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x10559a710>]
```

The code is a little cleaner using the callback.

Comment: Thank you for the example using a callback. I appreciate the use of squeee. :) I plan to implement a similar wrapper, like you did, although I'll look into how some of the map-based alternatives work. As I mentioned in my reply to Zsolt internally, I'm apprehensive about catch_warnings, but I'll give it a go, because I don't see an issue in practice.